# Create JavaScript native objects dynamically

Tags: javascript

Quite a long question.But it basically describe pretty much describe what i want.This code here for creating any object `according to user input` to a input text field.If i want to create Number,String or Object, i just have to write Number/String/Object in the `text field`.

a button has been introduced to call createObj.getObjName and get input from the text field.It tries to match the input for any three type of object which are Number/String/Object.Then it calls a bool function **`[problem lies here i think]`** which iterate over `**list_keys array**` using `Array.prototype.some` which is created using a json object that holds different object name.They are `assigned with objects` created using `new keyword`.

problem is to call check function i tried to forced the **`THIS keyword`** to indicate **`createObj`** object inside it instead of window object.I tried to **`console.log(this)`** it gives me this output which is the **`input html button element`**.

```
<input type='button' id='btn' value="create">
```

But i want THIS to refer to the createObj itself.**Why it is referring to HTML element ??How can i solve this?**

Full Code:

```
(function() {
    var list = {
        "Number": new Number(),
        "String": new String(),
        "Object": new Object(),
        "Array": new Array()
    }
    var list_keys = Object.keys(list);
    var createObj = {
        re: null,
        text: null,
        match: null,
        newObj: null,
        getObjName: function() {
            this.re = /Number|Object|String/;
            this.text = document.getElementById('text').value;
            this.match = this.text.match(this.re);
            var bool = check.call(this);
            if (bool) {
                this.makeObj(list.this.match[0]);
            }
        },
        makeObj: function(obj) {
            this.newObj = obj;
        }
    };

    function check() {
        console.log(this);
        return list_keys.some(function(el, indx, arr) {
            return this.match[0] === el;
        });
    }
    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', createObj.getObjName);
})();
```

Comment: why down vote this question.Is the question not clear?:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just bind the object, like this

```
createObj.getObjName.bind(createObj)
```

This will return a new function, with `this` referring `createObj` inside `getObjName`.

Also, what if there is no match at all?

```
return this.match[0] === el;
```

this will fail at run time, since `this.match` will be null. So you might want to do something like this

```
return this.match && list_keys.some(...);
```

If I were to write the same code, in a better way, I would do something like this

```
(function() {
    var MyObject = {
        newObject: null,
        createObject: function() {
            var text = document.getElementById('text').value;
            if (window.hasOwnProperty(text)) {
                this.newObject = new window[text];
            }
        }
    }

    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', 
        MyObject.createObject.bind(MyObject));

})();
```

Comment: I strongly maintain that in a situation like this then an additional alias closed over `this` (e.g. `var self = this`) is simpler to understand and more efficient than using `.bind`.  The latter IMHO should be reserved for cases where you don't control the lexical scope of the function you're trying to use `this` in.

Comment: @Alnitak Actually, I am not even sure why OP is doing this way. So, I just gave him the simplest alternative, without altering anyother part of the code.

Comment: True, it's not the easiest code to read, either.  I would have used `new` to create an actual instance instead of a static object containing method properties.

Comment: @Alnitak Oh my. Why didn't I think of that? Thanks :-) Updated the answer,

Comment: @thefourtheye what does window.hasOwnProperty(text) supposed to do ??there is no global text variable.And what's the purpose of the this.newObject=new Window[text] statement??new Window[] seems confusing.Can you clarify a little please?

Comment: @user3138436 What if user types "abcd"? There will be no such function, right? So, `window.hasOwnProperty(text)` will make sure that the function actually exists before calling it. If user enters `String`, then `window["String"]` will give the `String` constructor function. So, new `window["String"]()` will create a new `String` object.

Comment: this is kind of new concept for me.can you explain when window.hasOwnProperty(text) will be true?i mean is it a variable named text or something else?Is there a difference between text and string?

Comment: Text is the variable which we defined in the previous line

Comment: if so then why var text='lol';
console.log(window.hasOwnProperty(text)); it returns false?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63277/discussion-between-user3138436-and-thefourtheye).

Answer (score 1):

when you bind a function to an event, `this` refers to the html node the event was bound to. You can get around this in a variety of ways. The first that comes to mind is referencing `createObj` directly:

```
getObjName: function() {
    createObj.re = /Number|Object|String/;
    createObj.text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    createObj.match = this.text.match(createObj.re);
    var bool = check.call(createObj);
    if (bool) {
        this.makeObj(list.createObj.match[0]);
    }
},
```

this is less than ideal, because it references the object by name, which means if you change the object's name, you'll have to change all references to it. It also presents a problem if you (or another developer working with your code) defines a new `createObj` down the line. Since it is referencing the object by name it would start using the newly declared object instead of yours. An improvement would be to create an alias for the object (typically called that):

```
getObjName: function() {
    that.re = /Number|Object|String/;
    that.text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    that.match = this.text.match(that.re);
    var bool = check.call(that);
    if (bool) {
        this.makeObj(list.that.match[0]);
    }
},
...
var that = createObj
```

the problem with this is that `that` is usually meant to reference `this` in a scope where the context is lost, not an arbitrary object (in this case `createObj`).

Furthermore, I'm not sure that function belongs as a method of the `createObj`, or at least to the struct containing your data. Separation of concerns is important, and while

```
var createObj = {
    re: null,
    text: null,
    match: null,
    newObj: null,
```

is concerned with the data you're manipulating, `getObjName` and `makeObj` are concerned with event handling and fabricating an object using the collected data. I'd extract a struct out to hold the data, which I'd then use in my other objects:

```
var descriptors = {
    re: null,
    text: null,
    match: null,
    newObj: null
}

var getObjName = function() {
    descriptors.re = /Number|Object|String/;
    descriptors.text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    descriptors.match = descriptors.text.match(descriptors.re);
    var bool = check.call(descriptors);
    if (bool) {
        makeObj(list.descriptors.match[0]);
    }
}
var makeObj = function(obj) {
    this.newObj = obj;
}
function check() {
    console.log(this);
    return list_keys.some(function(el, indx, arr) {
        return this.match[0] === el;
    });
}
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', getObjName);
```

this separates struct from functionality, and better conveys the intent of the parts (`descriptors` holds all data, `getObjName` handles the event, and `makeObj` instantiates the new object).

there's still one issue with this though, from a design perspective, `getObjName` violates the Single Responsibility Principle. It is tasked with handling an event and getting the object's name. I'd refactor the event handling portion out to stay true to `getObjName`'s intent:

```
var getObjName = function(descriptors) {
    descriptors.re = /Number|Object|String/;
    descriptors.text = document.getElementById('text').value;
    descriptors.match = this.text.match(descriptors.re);
    return check.call(descriptors);
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (getObjName(descriptors)) {
        makeObj(list.descriptors.match[0]);
    }
});
```

Comment: I have some question regarding your answer.You wrote binding an object using its name may cause problem in future if i change the name.But in your fourth snippet you used the object name which is  (descriptor) all the time.And inside getObjName you used descriptors.match=this.text.match(descriptor.re);Here shouldn't THIS key cause the same indication problem again??I mean THIS inside a function refers to window

Comment: done. I also set descriptors up as a parameter (in the last block), to decouple it from the external struct